Finding the linked orders data in sql
trying to find the chain of orders using SQL query joining below two tables. If one order is dependent on two orders then the baseline order will be the one with minimum created_date.
Order table:



order_id
product
created_date




69980
table
11-12-2024


69981
stool
11-15-2024


69982
phone
11-23-2024


73396
car
10-11-2024


73395
bike
11-16-2024


73397
door
11-17-2024



Connection Table:



order_id
connection_id




69980



69981
69982


69981
69980


69982
69981


73395



73396



73397
73395


73397
73396



Expected data set:



order_id
connection_id
baseline




69980
69981
69980


69981
69980
69980


69981
69982
69980


69982
69981
69980


73396
null
73396


73395
null
73395


73397
73395
73396


73397
73396
73396



baseline for 73397 is 73396 base we need to pull the connection with least created_date from connection table.
Query ran -
  with order as (
    select
      order_id
    from
      order ord
  ),
  connection as (
    SELECT
      con.order_id,
      con.connection_id AS connect_order,
      ord.order_id
    FROM
      connection con
      join order ord on ord.order_id = con.order_id
    UNION
    SELECT
      con.connection_id,
      order_id AS connect_order,
      ord.order_id
    FROM
      connection con
      join order ord on ord.order_id = con.connection_id
  )
select distinct
  ord.order_id,
  con.order_id,
  con.linked_orders
from
  order ord
  left join connection con on ord.order_id = con.order_id


Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

oracle database

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; and an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement (including why the baseline is 73396 for the last 2 rows and not 73395 and where the 69982/null/69980 row comes from).

MT0 - Updated the question

You can use a correlated heierarchical sub-query:
SELECT c.order_id,
       c.connection_id,
       ( SELECT x.order_id
         FROM   connection x
                INNER JOIN orders o
                ON x.order_id = o.order_id
         START WITH c.order_id = x.order_id
         CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                PRIOR x.connection_id = x.order_id
         ORDER BY o.created_date ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) AS baseline
FROM   connection c

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Orders (order_id, product, created_date) AS
SELECT 69980, 'table', DATE '2024-11-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69981, 'stool', DATE '2024-11-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69982, 'phone', DATE '2024-11-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73396, 'car',   DATE '2024-10-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73395, 'bike',  DATE '2024-11-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73397, 'door',  DATE '2024-11-17' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Connection (order_id, connection_id) AS
SELECT 69980, NULL  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69981, 69982 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69981, 69980 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69982, 69981 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73395, NULL  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73396, NULL  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73397, 73395 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 73397, 73396 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ORDER_ID
CONNECTION_ID
BASELINE




69980
null
69980


69981
69982
69980


69981
69980
69980


69982
69981
69980


73395
null
73395


73396
null
73396


73397
73395
73396


73397
73396
73396



fiddle

This is working in source sql data base. Want to run the same in databricks sql. Throwing error there

@ASaraf I cannot help you as I do not use databricks.
